# Tell me which one is correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> (1) In English, we don't have many specific words or pronouns to show respect **like** lots of other languages do

Or

> (2) In English, we don't have many specific words or pronouns to show respect **unlike** lots of other languages do

Answer (score 1):

(1) is correct, although I would prefer:

> (1a) In English, we don't have many specific words or pronouns to show respect, as lots of other languages do.

(2) is not correct. To Use "unlike" rephrase to a form such as:

> - (3) Unlike lots of other languages, in English, we don't have many specific words or pronouns to show respect
> - (4) English is unlike lots of other languages, on that it does not have many specific words or pronouns to show respect.